# How to sort the RealmResults with recents dates?

Tags: realm, realm-list

I have around 20 rows in RealmResults and need to sort the list with recent dates

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()).build();
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
```

Like below

```
RealmResults<MyTable> List = realm.where(MyTable.class).findAll().sort("date",SORT.DESCENDING);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's really just the following.

```
RealmResults<MyTable> list = realm.where(MyTable.class)
                                .findAllSorted("date",Sort.DESCENDING);
```

And since 4.3.x:

```
RealmResults<MyTable> list = realm.where(MyTable.class)
                      .sort("date",Sort.DESCENDING)
                      .findAll();
```

Comment: I have to add the date values as like this "2014-12-06" in the table or Can I used Date Class itself in Realm.

Comment: as per [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#field-types), Realm supports the following field types: boolean, byte, short, ìnt, long, float, double, String, **Date** and byte[]. Please note that `Date` in Realm is **second**-precision, not *milisec* precision (it truncates milisec data to be compatible with iOS NSDate). If you need milisec precision, then use `long` and `date.getTime()`.

Comment: I don't want that much precise value. I am having format as(yyyy-MM-dd HH :mm:ss) and need to sort by date itself. What my question is. I need to save the date as (yyyy-MM-dd) and sort by Descending ?? or Convert that to Date Class  (yyyy-MM-dd)  and save it to DB.

Comment: in that case, RealmObjects support `java.util.Date` to second precision

Comment: Just want date, month and year,not even hours. Only this part, I need for comparison.

Comment: In that case, RealmObjects support `java.util.Date`

Comment: @476rick yes it is.

Comment: I commented so you could indeed update the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

```
realmResults.sort("Date", true);
```

Works with the Version `io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1`